# Creating a dead activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So I created a view which extends an activity which is my Welcome Screen.

For some absurd reason even though I overwrite the back command on the second screen using

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

to overwrite the back command on my second screen which becomes my main screen. I was able to go back to the original alpha view by going to a alert dialog press the back button really quickly and repeatedly it must have registered and saved the back command 5 times going back to the welcome screen.

Now my question is how do I ensure that I can never go back to that activity ever again.

The purpose of that activity is a loading and welcome screen.

Answer (score 2):

call `finish()` on that activity when you are done with it or you can set in the manifest that the activity has `noHistory="true"`

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time following most of what you wrote, but if you want to only show an `Activity` without being able to go back to it, in the manifest for that `Activity`, add this line:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```